Problem building Vue solution with @azure/msal-browser package included
I am running into an issue where my 'npm run build' is failing when I include the '@azure/msal-browser' package. It is failing when trying to parse the .mjs files from the package.
The specific error that I'm getting is this

error  in ./node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/dist/event/EventHandler.mjs
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

I'm finding posts related to this issue that suggested adding the following to the vue.config.js file
     chainWebpack: (config) => {
      config.module.rule('javascript/auto').test(/\.mjs$/)
    }

I tried that to no avail.
Also here is the content of my package.json file
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.19.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@handsontable/vue": "^12.3.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "flush-promises": "^1.0.2",
    "handsontable": "^12.3.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nanoid": "^5.0.7",
    "single-spa-vue": "^1.5.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.8.2",
    "systemjs-webpack-interop": "^1.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.7.16",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.18",
      "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.18",
      "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.18",
      "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~4.5.18",
      "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.18",
      "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.18",
      "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.0",
      "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.31",
      "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.4",
      "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
      "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
      "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.0.0",
      "@babel/compat-data": "^7.9.0",
      "@babel/core": "^7.14.6", 
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
      "chai": "^4.1.2",
      "cross-env": "^7.0.1",
      "eslint": "^6.7.2",
      "eslint-plugin-chai-friendly": "^0.5.0",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
      "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
      "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
      "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
      "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
      "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
      "karma": "^4.4.1",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
      "karma-coverage": "^2.0.1",
      "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
      "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
      "karma-sinon-chai": "^2.0.2",
      "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
      "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
      "karma-webpack": "^4.0.2",
      "sass": "^1.58.3",
      "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
      "sinon": "^9.0.0",
      "sinon-chai": "^3.5.0",
      "vue-cli-plugin-single-spa": "~1.1.0",
      "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.16"
    }

I have to use Azure authentication so I have no choice but to get this figured out.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
TIA,
Bill
After further t/s involving running vue-cli-service inspect I've noticed the following differences in my solution and one what '@azure/msal-browser' is working just fine.
My vue.config inspection results
      /* config.module.rule('mjs') */
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        include: [
          /node_modules/
        ]
      },

      /* config.module.rule('js') */
      {
        test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          function () { /* omitted long function */ }
        ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'C:\\Users\\bill.youngman\\source\\repos\\CAT-Touchstone\\cat-touchstone-re-ui\\node_modules\\cache-loader\\dist\\cjs.js',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: 'C:\\Users\\bill.youngman\\source\\repos\\CAT-Touchstone\\cat-touchstone-re-ui\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader',
              cacheIdentifier: '0582bb69'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'C:\\Users\\bill.youngman\\source\\repos\\CAT-Touchstone\\cat-touchstone-re-ui\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js'
          }
        ]
      },

Solution where msal-browser is working fine
/* config.module.rule('js') */
      {
        test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          function () { /* omitted long function */ }
        ],
        use: [
          /* config.module.rule('js').use('babel-loader') */
          {
            loader: 'C:\\Users\\bill.youngman\\source\\repos\\CAT-Tools\\cat-edm-reporter\\vuefront\\vuepage\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js',
            options: {
              cacheCompression: false,
              cacheDirectory: 'C:\\Users\\bill.youngman\\source\\repos\\CAT-Tools\\cat-edm-reporter\\vuefront\\vuepage\\node_modules\\.cache\\babel-loader',
              cacheIdentifier: 'c8f04554'
            }
          }
        ]
      }

Notice that mine has this that the good config doesn't...
/* config.module.rule('mjs') */
...also my config.module.rule('js') is pointing to node_modules\cache-loader whereas the good config is pointing to node_modules\babel-loader
There are a couple of other differences but these ones jumped out at me.

I fixed my issue - it ended up being finding the right packages that needed updating.
My package file ended up looking like this--
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.11.1",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.37.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "single-spa-vue": "^3.0.0",
    "standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "systemjs-webpack-interop": "^2.3.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-json-excel": "^0.2.98",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.7.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.10",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.5",
    "dot-env": "0.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.22.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "husky": "^7.0.1",
    "jest-expect-message": "^1.0.2",
    "jest-junit": "^13.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.33.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-single-spa": "^3.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.9.2",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }

